# SharePoint online management shell is not getting installed

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I have installed PowerShell 3.0 with wmf3.0 kb2506143 in my system and downloaded SharePointOnlineManagementShell_8029-1200_x64_en-us.msi file. But every time I am getting an error saying – “Required PowerShell 3.0” and the management shell is not getting installed.

Comment: Perhaps you installed the 32-bit version of Powershell? Why not go for a higher version?

Comment: We have tried with 64 bit. Also tried with higher version of power shell(4 and 5). But we are getting same error while installing.

Comment: On what OS are you installing? Did you restart the pc after installing Powershell setup? Although it is an older post, maybe your problem is similar to [this blog](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/marios_mo_betta_blog/2014/01/23/installing-the-sharepoint-online-management-shell-on-windows-8-1/)?